# Excluding empty spaces from being counted In Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

In Python 3, how do I exclude an empty space from being counted in a sentence?

**Example**:

```py
name = input('Please enter your name: ')
greetings = input('Hi {}, please enter a sentence here: '.format(name))
print(str(name) + ', your sentence has ' + str(len(greetings)) + ' characters.')
```

When I run this program, it counts all characters that I enter into the input and it also counts the empty spaces, too. But I only want the program to count the characters, not the empty spaces.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

`greetings = input('Hi {}, please enter a sentence here: '.format(name))`

use
`greetings = input('Hi {}, please enter a sentence here: '.format(name.replace(" ","")))`

basically he takes every empty space from name and replaces it with nothing

Answer (score 0):

there can be many solutions to this problem.
I suggest to use regex, which is highly flexible and robust at the sametime.

Below is the code -

```
import re 

def remove(string): 
    pattern = re.compile(r'\s+') 
    return re.sub(pattern, '', string)
name = input('Please enter your name: ')
greetings = input('Hi {}, please enter a sentence here: '.format(name))
print(str(name) + ', your sentence has ' + str(len(remove(greetings))) + ' characters.')
```

Good luck, enjoy!!

Comment: 'PERFECT', thank you so much for your help, problem solved!